# What will be the correct type of "any"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, frontend

I am using the following in my code base :

https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react

But they have not explained the types used for map and maps which is giving me typescript error. Changing it to object does not help much.

`const handleApiLoaded = (map: any, maps: any) => {`

What is the correct types of map and maps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Thanks

````
      map: google.maps.Map;
      maps: {
        LatLngBounds: new () => google.maps.LatLngBounds;
      };```
````

Answer (score 0):

For packages that don't supply first-class typings themselves, DefinitelyTyped usually provides them as is the case here. Install the [@types/google-map-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-map-react) package and you should receive proper types, code completion and type checking.

Comment: Using this already, can you direct me to the specific types. Thanks.